# Generate Client using OpenApi generator create several unwanted jars in generated target

Tags: java, maven, openapi-generator, java-17

Hello Maven Community,

I'm a beginner, I apology if I do technical (or english) mistakes.

I'm trying to deploy only the main jar of my generated client.

My problem is that the client generates several jar when compiled (in client's target) :

- the desired main jar project-name-client.jar that I want to deploy at the end
- 3 unwanted jar project-name-client-javadoc.jar, project-name-client-sources.jar and project-name-client-tests.jar

Here is my config to generate the client

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/swagger/swagger.json</inputSpec>

                            <generatorName>java</generatorName>
                            <library>native</library>

                            <output>${project.basedir}/../${project.artifactId}-client</output>
                            <apiPackage>${apiPackage}</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>${modelPackage}</modelPackage>
                            <invokerPackage>${invokerPackage}</invokerPackage>

                            <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                            <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>

                            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                            <artifactId>${project.artifactId}-client</artifactId>
                            <artifactVersion>${project.version}</artifactVersion>

                            <configOptions>
                                <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
                                <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
                                <openApiNullable>false</openApiNullable>

                                <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                                <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>

                                <parentGroupId>${project.parent.groupId}</parentGroupId>
                                <parentArtifactId>${project.parent.artifactId}</parentArtifactId>
                                <parentVersion>${project.parent.version}</parentVersion>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I tried to block the generation but didn't find a working solution yet.

I tried to use maven ant run plugin to delete the jars before deploy (from the server's pom) but it seems the client generation/compile comes after the plugin.Because the client is generated, I can't modify the client's pom which is regenerated.